# JVM crashes on Ubuntu trying to open JavaFX Save Dialog or Open Dialog

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, javafx

In Windows everything works well , i am just using JavaFX and Java 1.8.0_131 to choose a File from the Operating System.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fa5f45cde90, pid=4843, tid=0x00007fa59b31c700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libpthread.so.0+0x9e90]  pthread_mutex_lock+0x0
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/alexander/Desktop/Roots/hs_err_pid4843.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Code that you can use:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public final class FileChooserSample extends Application {

    private Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("File Chooser Sample");

        final FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

        final Button openButton = new Button("Open a Picture...");
        final Button openMultipleButton = new Button("Open Pictures...");

        openButton.setOnAction(
            new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(final ActionEvent e) {
                    configureFileChooser(fileChooser);
                    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
                    if (file != null) {
                        openFile(file);
                    }
                }
            });

        openMultipleButton.setOnAction(
            new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(final ActionEvent e) {
                    configureFileChooser(fileChooser);
                    List<File> list = 
                        fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(stage);
                    if (list != null) {
                        for (File file : list) {
                            openFile(file);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        final GridPane inputGridPane = new GridPane();

        GridPane.setConstraints(openButton, 0, 0);
        GridPane.setConstraints(openMultipleButton, 1, 0);
        inputGridPane.setHgap(6);
        inputGridPane.setVgap(6);
        inputGridPane.getChildren().addAll(openButton, openMultipleButton);

        final Pane rootGroup = new VBox(12);
        rootGroup.getChildren().addAll(inputGridPane);
        rootGroup.setPadding(new Insets(12, 12, 12, 12));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(rootGroup));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

        private static void configureFileChooser(final FileChooser fileChooser){                           
        fileChooser.setTitle("View Pictures");
        fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(
            new File(System.getProperty("user.home"))
        ); 
    }


    private void openFile(File file) {
        try {
            desktop.open(file);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(
                FileChooserSample.class.getName()).log(
                    Level.SEVERE, null, ex
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Above code is taken from Oracle Tutorials -> [!Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/file-chooser.htm)

Comment: What's your kernel version? I recall seeing reports about a recent bug introduced to the kernel that breaks Java in some cases. See, e.g.: https://askubuntu.com/questions/927746/eclipse-crashes-with-linux-kernel-4-4-0-81-generic

Comment: @sillyfly I have the latest Ubuntu version **Ubuntu 17.04**

Comment: This also applies to 17.04. See [this message](https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3345-1/)  (Not sure you are seeing the same issue, but simply being on 17.04 does not automatically mean it's not that).

Comment: @sillyfly O_O Thank you :) I will try it .